# Angular elements locating

Tags: java, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Since that just started with new project which is in Angular (and also have another project on which tests are written in **Java** therefore would not use Protractor if is any possibility), have a difficulty in locating element with xpath.
Please assist me (although it looked at first view very simple) in finding **Home** button, it appears to me as a great confusion. Here is page source:

```
<ul _ngcontent-c9="" class="be-inline-menu be-font--be">

    <!---->
      <!---->

      <!----><be-inline-menu-item _ngcontent-c2="" _nghost-c10="" class=""><li _ngcontent-c10="" class="be-inline-menu__item">
    <a _ngcontent-c10="" class="be-inline-menu__item__inner be-typo-be be-inline-menu__item__inner--is-active" href="/home">
     Home
   <!---->
```

So, tried with this one (while inspecting element) and got nothing:

```
//ul[@_ngcontent-c9.class='be-inline-menu be-font--be']//a
```

Thank you in advance.
 [image]

Comment: You need to show us a bit more of the `HTML`. Currently it is not clear where `<ul>`, `<li>` and `<a>` tag is ending.

Comment: @DebanjanB Added screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the button with text as **`Home`** you can use either of the following options :

- **`cssSelector`** :

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ul.be-inline-menu.be-font--be a.be-inline-menu__item__inner.be-typo-be.be-inline-menu__item__inner--is-active[href=/home]")).click();
  ```
- **`xpath`** :

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='be-inline-menu be-font--be']//a[@class='be-inline-menu__item__inner be-typo-be be-inline-menu__item__inner--is-active' and @href='/home']")).click();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

try this xpath
**.//a[contains(text(), 'Home')]**
also you can do it with css selector **a[href="/home"]**

Comment: Tried xpath, not founding element.